# What is the warning that pandas is trying to tell me?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have the following code which simply has a function that takes in an input dataframe and outputs a version that groups them by `label` and sums them.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed = 10

input_data = np.array(
[
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['g'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['g'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['a'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['b'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(4)]+['b']
]
)

input_df = pd.DataFrame(data=input_data, columns=['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'label'])

def group_and_sum(input_df):
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for gr,subdf in input_df.groupby('label'):
        new_df = pd.DataFrame()

        new_df['label'] = [gr]
        columns = [x for x in input_df.columns if x!='label']
        subdf[columns] = subdf[columns].values.astype(float)
        for col in columns:
            new_df[col] = [sum(subdf[col].values)]

        new_df['sum'] = sum([new_df[x].values for x in columns])
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df, new_df])
    final_df.index = np.array(range(len(final_df)))
    return final_df

final_df = group_and_sum(input_df)
```

which throws the following warning:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.17.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2269
    self.ix._setitem_with_indexer((slice(None), indexer), value)
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Two things:

1)  When I check out the warning [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)  it doesn't seem to be relevant to me.  I'm not doing anything like `chained-indexing` as the link provided in the warning indicates.

2)  When I try to reproduce the error outside of the function, I cannot for some reason:

```
input_df[['A']]=input_df[['A']].astype(float)
input_df[['A','B']]=input_df[['A','B']].astype(float)
```

...those both run perfectly fine.

Is there another way to reproduce this warning, and does it apply here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the warning is because of your line `subdf[columns] = subdf[columns].values.astype(float)`.  You got `subdf` from the groupby, so `subdf` is a reference to some rows of the original DataFrame.  Setting values on this slice leads to the warning.  In other words, it is as if you did chained indexing:

```
input_df[rows_that_are_part_of_this_group][columns] = ...
```

Comment: Okay, so I guess what you're telling me is that somehow the `"subdf"` still refers or points back to `input_df`?  I guess there is some nuance in a `groupby` object that does this.

Comment: This is the only way I am able to reproduce the warning:  `input_df[input_df['label']=='g']['label'] = input_df['A']`  Although, it is still unclear to me how this is any more dangerous than, say `input_df[['A']]=input_df[['A']].astype(float)` (which is in my question)

Comment: @Hunle: It's not that it's "dangerous", it's just that it is sometimes slower.  Also, if you have a complex series of slicing operations, sometimes they may not update the original object when you assign.